# Java - read bytes at given offset

Tags: java, offset

I'm having a little trouble in understanding how I can read and return the value of a certain offset position in a file.

For example, I know from my hex editor that the offset is D768, and the value is 32bit. So how can read this value and display it in a label.

Any help at all will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that java.io.RandomAccessFile is your new friend :-)

Beware of the following code, it has not been tested.

```
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("foo.bin", "r");
raf.seek(0xd768);
int value = raf.read();
```

Comment: +1: I would use readInt() (read a 32-bit int) instead of read() (reads an unsigned byte)

Comment: Cheers, fellas, this is very helpful. I think I can take it from here. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Use the DataInputStream class.  Open the file, and position it using `skipBytes(offset)`, and then call `readInt()`.  This will give you a 32 bit starting at the offset you used.

(Note that this assumes that the integer is represented in the file in with the most significant byte first.)

Comment: This is not always working. Skip does not always skip offset number of bytes. (That is why it returns the actual number of skipped bytes).

Comment: @MTilsted - then you keep skipping until you've reached the requisite number of bytes.  In practice, I think you will find `skipBytes` will only "not work" **on a file** if offset is beyond the end of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Use `skipBytes` to get to given position. To read 32-bit number you can use `DataInputStream` if the value is big-endian. If it's little endian you need to manually convert four bytes to `int`:

```
int value = (int)bytes[0]
        | ((int)bytes[1] << 8)
        | ((int)bytes[2] << 16)
        | ((int)bytes[3] << 24);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [RandomAccessFile.skipBytes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#skipBytes%28int%29) skipping until offset, that class might help you.